# How to upgrade JUnit version in Intelliji (from 4.11 to latest one)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit4, junit5, junit-jupiter

It's not really coding question but I'm stuck on it. I start new Java project in Intelliji and add tests with JUnit5. In this tests I'm using `@Role` annotation for [FakeSftpServerRule github library](https://github.com/stefanbirkner/fake-sftp-server-rule).

I added all jupiter dependencies I just can thought about them in the pom file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
    <version>5.6.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

It's the way to initialize the fake ftp:

```
@Rule
public final FakeSftpServerRule fakeSftpServer = new FakeSftpServerRule()
   .addUser(username, password)
   .setPort(port);
```

And I'm using regular other attributes, like `@BeforeAll` and `@Test`...

Running the tests throw this error:

> Internal Error occurred. org.junit.platform.commons.JUnitException:
>   TestEngine with ID 'junit-vintage' failed to discover tests   at
>   org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discoverEngineRoot(DefaultLauncher.java:189)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discoverRoot(DefaultLauncher.java:168)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:132)
>     at
>   com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
>     at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
>   Caused by: org.junit.platform.commons.JUnitException: Unsupported
>   version of junit:junit: 4.11-beta-1. Please upgrade to version 4.12 or
>   later.    at
>   org.junit.vintage.engine.JUnit4VersionCheck.checkSupported(JUnit4VersionCheck.java:39)
>     at
>   org.junit.vintage.engine.JUnit4VersionCheck.checkSupported(JUnit4VersionCheck.java:32)
>     at
>   org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.discover(VintageTestEngine.java:62)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discoverEngineRoot(DefaultLauncher.java:181)

Now, by navigate to source I found that `@BeforeAll` and `@Test` annotations point on `junit-jupiter 5.5.2` but `@Role` point on `junit 4.11 (beta-1)`.

How can I get rid from junit 4.11 and update it to the latest version?

Comment: https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#migrating-from-junit4 -- and also please align the versions of JUnit Platform (1.6.1), Jupiter, and Vintage: 5.6.1

Browse/copy starter project here: https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples

Comment: If you are getting unexpected dependencies, it's often useful to run `mvn dependency:tree` to see where they are coming from.

Comment: Thanks both! @Sormuras, I see you link, thanks! so `@Rule` is not supported in Junit5, thereare some workarounds but I decide to downgrade to junit4. Thanks!